# find specific special characters in string

Tags: java, regex, string, special-characters

I am looking for a regex pattern for finding out if any of the 4 specific special characters is present in a string variable : apostrophe (') en dash (-) em dash (—) upside down question mark (¿)

I tried Contains method of string but using that I'll have to compare 4 times:

```
abc.contains("'")||abc.contains("-")||abc.contains("—")||abc.contains("¿")
```

Is there a better way using regex? since I have to implement the same for many variables.

May I also know which character was found specifically in shortest possible way?

Comment: Note that's not actually an en dash, it's a hyphen. Hyphen: -, minus: −, en dash: –, em dash: —.

Comment: May I also know which character was found specifically in shortest possible way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this way

```
if (abc.matches(".*?['\\-—¿].*"))
```

If will accept any string matching this sequence:

- `.*` - zero or more of any characters (beside new lines)
- `['\\-—¿]` - one of `'` `-` `—` `¿` (`-` is special character in regex character class - `[...]` - so I needed to escape it with `\` which in Java has to be written as `"\\"` or place it right after `[` or just before `]`)
- `.*` - again zero or more of any characters (beside new lines)

Comment: Why the `.*`? They're only here to slow the regex... `abc.matches("[-'—¿]")` is plainly enough (also the hyphen can be put as first or last character of a character class so you don't have to escape it).

Comment: @Loamhoof `matches` will return true only if *entire* string matches regex, so `.*` is essential. It is true that placing hyphen as firs or last element of character class will also make it literal, but I prefer to escape it since it will prevent future errors if for instance when someone else with no regex knowledge will try to add new characters to character class.

Comment: @Pshemo at least use a lazy operator then `.*?`